# Find min value in 2D Array and sort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I'm completely new to java and programming in general, i could use a little help with part of an exercise i need to do for uni.

I have a 2D array list containing info on various music albums (title, artist, number of tracks, length in minutes, price, etc) 
I need to create a list containing all the albums sorted by price in ascending order.

I'm a little overwhelmed by all the steps I need to take - run through the array list and look at a specific position ([`i][position price]`), convert the price from string to array, find the minimum value, transport that into a new list and delete it from the existing one.

I know this is vague but like I said I'm a complete beginner, I'd appreciate it if someone could help me break down the steps.

Peace, thanks, R

*P.s. I'm learning in German so I'm not sure I used the right vocab everywhere!*

Comment: Why don't you just start with the simple steps like looping through an array and look at a value at a specific position like you proposed? If you then run into troubles, come back, show us your code and we can guide you from there.

Comment: There are many different sorting algorithms. Were you told the specific steps to sort, or are you supposed to invent it on your own?

Comment: You have to put the main pieces of your code for us to understand exactly your problem. Why do you have a 2D Array (what is in the second dimension)? How do you expect this to magically become a list?

Comment: By *2D array list* possibly you mean a *2D array*?

Answer (score 0):

```
   Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Albums>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Albums o1, Albums o2) {
            return o1.price < o2.price ? 1:-1;
        }

    });
```

or lambda

```
Collections.sort(list, (o1,  o2) -> o1.price < o2.price ? 1:-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple list, assuming the price is an integer, you can just do it by:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Album::getPrice))
```

If it is an array, you can similarly do it with:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(Album::getPrice))
```

If `price` is a floating point number you can similarly use `comparingDouble`.

You didn't provide any info about your code, so difficult to say what works in your situation.